# Failed to resolve: com.truecaller.android.sdk:truecaller-sdk:2.6.0 Show in Project Structure dialog<

Tags: structure, project

there are problem when i implementing

Failed to resolve: com.truecaller.android.sdk:truecaller-sdk:2.6.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 1):

if You are using build tool version `7.1.0` or more:
Add the `jcenter()` function in the `settings.gradle` file.
As `Truecaller sdk` supports `jcenter()`.